# Centering Modal Title and button in React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to implement React Modal for my project. I want to center the Modal Title and Modal Button. I tried to use flex and just-content-center but it didn't work. Any suggestions would be valuable.

```
<Modal show={modalShow} onHide={this.handleClose} aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" centered>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <Modal.Title>{isVerified?"Submitted succesfully":"Failed to submit"}</Modal.Title>
        </div> 
    </Modal.Header>
         <Modal.Footer>
    <Button variant={`${isVerified == false?"danger ":"success"}`} onClick={this.handleClose} centered>
        {isVerified?"Ok":"Try again"}
    </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried different classes but what is working is this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const ModalPage = ({ modalShow, handleClose, isVerified }) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      show={modalShow}
      onHide={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header
        closeButton
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Modal.Title>
          {isVerified ? "Submitted succesfully" : "Failed to submit"}
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>          
      <Modal.Footer
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Button
          variant={`${isVerified == false ? "danger " : "success"}`}
          onClick={handleClose}
          centered
        >
          {isVerified ? "Ok" : "Try again"}
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default ModalPage;
```

Comment: Great!
If you're using dialogClassName for an edited class or Modal.Header style doesn't seem to have effect, try adding "width: 100%;" property

Answer (score 3):

**For centering the header title and close button:**

If you increase the horizontal padding and use ms-auto on the title you can move the close button to an appropriate spot while keeping the title text centered.

```
<Modal>
  <Modal.Header className="px-4" closeButton>
    <Modal.Title className="ms-auto">Title</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>Body</Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```